# cmi.exit data model element in SCORM 2004 3rd edition

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I couldn't understand the usage of cmi.exit data model element.

**Scenario A:** Suppose an activity sets its `cmi.success_status = passed` and `cmi.exit = suspend` and then triggers an `Exit All` navigation request. In this case, what is the value of `Objective Satisfied Status` of the primary objective of the activity in the next Sequencing Session?

**Scenario B:** Suppose an activity sets its `cmi.success_status = passed` and `cmi.exit = normal` and then triggers an `Exit All` navigation request. In this case, what is the value of `Objective Satisfied Status` of the primary objective of the activity in the next Sequencing Session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both scenarios, the next sequencing session will start with fresh data because of "Exit All" NAV request. If a SCO sets the value of "cmi.exit" data to "suspend", this will suspend that SCO while the sequencing session is in progress. If you want to retain all data for the whole course, you should use "Suspend All" instead of "Exit All". Notice that "cmi.exit" is related only to the SCO which trigers it, it does not affect other SCOs in the course.